# MySQL where comparison operator in a match search

Tags: php, mysql, regex

Below is the SQL statement, I am having difficulty placing a where statement that gets the score generated by match and only return products that score over 6.

```
SELECT product_id, image, title, part_num, price, discount_id, vat, 
       MATCH (title,part_num,description) 
       AGAINST ('SEARCH HERE') AS score 
FROM main_products AS p 
WHERE status = 1 
     AND MATCH(title,part_num,description) AGAINST ('SEARCH HERE') 
ORDER BY score desc, title ASC
```

I have tried but this doesn't work. It results in this error: Documentation #1054 - Unknown column 'score' in 'where clause'

```
SELECT product_id, image, title, part_num, price, discount_id, vat, 
      MATCH (title,part_num,description) 
      AGAINST ('SEARCH HERE') AS score 
FROM main_products AS p WHERE status = 1 AND score > 6 
     AND MATCH(title,part_num,description) AGAINST ('SEARCH HERE') 
ORDER BY score desc, title ASC
```

Comment: Define *"it doesn't work"*. Use the tools at your disposal, such as `mysql_error` or `mysqli_error` or PDO equivalent and you'll see the error.

Comment: maybe you just missed AND here `status = 1 AND score > 6` ?

Comment: Hi Fred sorry for not being clearer, the second code I posted results in the following error:  MySQL said: Documentation
#1054 - Unknown column 'score' in 'where clause'

Comment: You're obviously missing either an `AND` or an `OR` in your statement, depending on what your criteria is.

Comment: I was going to say something @Fred -ii- , but I'll just leave it at *Mornin' Ralph*

Comment: @JayBlanchard *Mornin' Sam*

Comment: Hi Fred-ii- and Kim Alexander I have inserted the AND statement but that still results in the Documentation #1054 - Unknown column 'score' in 'where clause'. The score column is generated as part of Match.

Comment: so just try to remove `that score` out  from `WHERE status = 1 AND 
     AND (MATCH(title,part_num,description) AGAINST ('SEARCH HERE')) >6`

Comment: Hi Alex you are a star! Thank you

Comment: You are welcome, I just read the error message and try to avoid it :-)

Answer (score 0):

How with this?

```
SELECT product_id, image, title, part_num, price, discount_id, vat, 
      MATCH (title,part_num,description) 
      AGAINST ('SEARCH HERE') AS score 
FROM main_products 
WHERE status = 1 
      AND MATCH(title,part_num,description) AGAINST ('SEARCH HERE')
HAVING score > 6 
ORDER BY score desc, title ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

MySQL first uses WHERE condition to retrieve rows, and then SELECT the columns.

So the "score" is not something known when MySQL selects rows.

You have to use the `HAVING score > 6` as Angga said in his post in order to use this, or `WHERE MATCH(...) AGAINST(...) > 6` as Alex said in his comment.

Both will return the same results, but performance consideration should make you prefer using WHERE because it won't make additional work on columns in order to filter the selection (like when using HAVING) and it will only read index files for selection.